# another initialize a static c++ class member

Tags: c++

Righty ho, so I've read through several similar questions and I still do not understand why this code does not work.

I simply want to write a class with a static int member.  Then increment the static member by using different instances.  I do not understand why this doesn't work.  Please help a c++ nub.

```
class Timer {
public:
    static int seconds;
    Timer() {}
    void tick();
    std::string to_string();
};
void Timer::tick() {
    Timer::seconds++;
}
std::string Timer::to_string() {
    return ("Timer: " + std::to_string(Timer::seconds) + "s.\n");
}


int main() {
    Timer::seconds = 0;
    Timer s = Timer();
    Timer t = Timer();
    s.tick();
    t.tick();
    std::cout << s.to_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.to_string() << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: There are several similar questions in the **Related** sidebar. They all give the same answer as the one below.

Comment: static class variable should be initialize outside of main();
only const variable can be initialize inside class; like, const static int seconds=0; but, can't modify its value later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a line

```
int Timer::seconds = 0;
```

outside the class definition. Such as:

```
class Timer {
public:
    static int seconds;
    Timer() {}
    void tick();
    std::string to_string();
};

int Timer::seconds = 0;
```

The line

```
    static int seconds;
```

only declares the `static` member variable. It must be defined outside using the above syntax.